# Kubernetes logs spamming Splunk

Tags: splunk-query

I'm having issues with Kubernetes containers spamming Splunk with hundreds of gigabytes of logs sometimes. I would like to put together a search to track containers that have a sudden log spike and generate an alert.

More specifically:

1. look at the average rate of events
2. find the peak
3. decide a percentage of that peak
4. and then trigger an alert when a container has breached the threshold.

The closest I have come up with is the below search, which has an average rate and standard deviation of that rate by hour:

```
index="apps" sourcetype="kube"
| bucket _time span=1h
| stats count as CountByHour by _time, kubernetes.container_name
| eventstats avg(CountByHour) as AvgByKCN stdev(CountByHour) as StDevByKCN by kubernetes.container_name
```